# Google Sheets - Conditional Formatting based on column heading of cell value

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I've had a problem that's been bugging me for days and I can't quite figure it out. Scenario:

1. **Names:** This is an unsorted sheet where there are a bunch of names.
2. **Team**: This is another unsorted sheet, but each name belongs to one of four teams indicated by a column and its header - Alpha, Beta, Charlie & Delta

I'm trying to come up with a conditional formatting formula for the **Names** sheet whereby it would, for example, colour names of people belonging to Alpha Team RED, Beta team GREEN, etc.

Example:

**NAMES**

```
Barry
Harrison
Oliver
Caitlin
Hartley
```

**TEAM**

```
ALPHA         BETA         CHARLIE         DELTA
Barry         Harrison     Hartley         Oliver
Caitlin
```

So in the above examples, in the **Names** sheet, Barry and Caitlin's names would be coloured **red** since they're in ALPHA team. Harrison would be **green** since he's in BETA team; and so forth.

Comment: Please add some example data to your question. It's very difficult to understand it now.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Sorry, added some sample data and an explanations. Hope that makes it clearer

Comment: What product do you use? Excel or Google? There are differences, so don't tag with both. You're wasting people's time.

Comment: @teylyn My bad; fully aware they're different products but I've gotten away with using them interchangeably recently so my fault. Clarified it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel you need four rules, one for each color.

[image]

The yellow rule is

=MATCH(A1,Teams!$A:$A,0)

The other ones use the columns B, C and D on the Teams sheet. In earlier versions of Excel, pre 2010, I think, you cannot reference ranges on other sheets in a CF formula. You can use named ranges instead, though.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using MATCH before but it didn't work as intended since I messed up trying to apply the formula to an entire range and typed it incorrectly.

Solved it with this and three other iterations with columns B, C and D

`=MATCH(A1, INDIRECT("Divisions!$A:$A"), 0)`

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why you would use Indirect() here.